# How to reference a document with xsl in a java package

Tags: java, xml, xslt

For my project I have a package own package (xml) with xsl files.
And when I need one I just get the file with:

```
String xsl=getTextResource(this,"../xml/rob.xsl");
```

and the transformation works as expected

```
TransformerFactory tFactory=getTransformerFactory();

        Transformer transformer=tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

        if(xslParameters !=null) {
            for(Parameter p:xslParameters) {
                transformer.setParameter(p.getName(), p.getStringValue());
            }
        }

        result=XMLHelper.createDocument();
        DOMResult resultStream=new DOMResult(result);

        transformer.transform(xmlSource, resultStream);
```

However my Problem arises with the statements:

```
  <xsl:param name="matcherPath">.</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="parameterPath"  select="concat($matcherPath,'/','rob_parameters.xml')" />
  <xsl:variable name="zuordnungsTabelle" select="document(concat($matcherPath,'/','rob_matcher.xml'))" />
  <xsl:variable name="parameterTabelle"  select="document($parameterPath)" />
```

The transformer searches in the file system, but not in the class file. So the Files could not be found.

Is the a possibility that the transformer seeks for other documents in the package and not in the filesystem?

Comment: Implement/set https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setURIResolver(javax.xml.transform.URIResolver) to ensure the relative URIs are resolved to read from your package and not from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin, that was the right hint to solve this.

```
...
 TransformerFactory tFactory=getTransformerFactory();
...
tFactory.setURIResolver(resolver);
```

resolver is a class that implements URIResolver which implements the function resolve. (A bit quick and dirty solution ... but it works)

```
@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
    Source result=null;
    // System.out.println("href="+href+" base="+base);
    try {
        String resultString=getTextResource(this,"../xml/"+href);
        result=new StreamSource(new StringReader(resultString));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RoB_TransferGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new TransformerException("href="+href+" base="+base+ " not found");
    }

    return result;
}
```